# How to handle clicks on a label of NVD3 PieChart?

Tags: charts, nvd3.js

To handle clicks on NVD3 pie chart slices you can do the following:

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
... 
chart.pie.dispatch.on("elementClick", function(e) {
    var pie_sector_name = e.data.label;
    // do something;
});
```

However, I receive clicks when the pie slices are selected. Is it possible to handle clicks when the chart labels are selected? Pie slices could be sometimes just so tiny that it is impossible to click on them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 d3.selectAll(".nv-pieLabels").on("click", function () {
    alert("clicked");
 });
```

Comment: When a pie chart is created, it's labels have 'nv-pieLavels' class ('g' elements in chart 'svg'). You can select them with d3 selector and handle click event. For some reason, this does not work for me :(

Comment: The fact is, `d3.selectAll(".nv-series")` works (for the legend elements), and `d3.selectAll(".nv-pieLabels")` (for the chart labels) does not. Weird